# How to silent a single specific log line using slf4j settings

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I get the following log line while running the mvn tests. I don want to take any actions for that, since its just running the tests on H2 database.

```
WARN  org.hibernate.orm.connections - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
```

I can put something like following to silent the logs from whole package.

```
  <Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.connections" level="fatal"/>
```

But i **don't** want whole class or whole package to be silent. I just need to skip printing that specific log line. How can i configure my log4j2.xml file ?

Comment: I guess you can't because you declare log on packaging basis, so you if you try omitting the org.hibernate.orm it will not show any log from that package it self. Lets see if someone has some way to do it.

Comment: Maybe a [RegEx-Filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter)? With OnMatch=DENY, OnMismatch=NEUTRAL ...

Comment: I think since you have problem with only this log statement then you can look into https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ec4f20a5fba79444dbd704f1305f961c339dd7d1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/log/ConnectionPoolingLogger.java#L42 . If there is some way to change this log level with some config.

Answer (score 0):

As Fildor suggested your best bet is to use the RegExFilter. I would key on HHH10001002. But I would only do this under the org.hibernate.orm.connections Logger.

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.connections" level="WARN">
   <RegExFilter regex="^HHH10001002: .*" onMatch="DENY" onMisMatch="NEUTRAL"/>
</Logger>
```

This will only filter messages using Loggers under that package so the overhead of filtering won't affect your application very much. It will let the messages that are at the WARN, ERROR or FATAL and don't match the pattern through and they will fall through to their parent configured logger (or the root) for routing to an appender.

(Edit May 11, 2016): After googling a bit I believe the text of the message actually starts with HHH1001002:, so I have edited the regex above to match. I am not sure if the logger name is correct though. You should check and see if %c is in the pattern for your PatternLayout. If it is not you may need to add it to determine the actual Logger name to use.

Comment: I tired this. But sadly didn't work. Still its printing. May be its my some other configuration issue. I'll check more

Comment: @dinesh707 I am not sure if the RegEx will hit. You may try a unique term inside the message itself. For example "Using Hibernate". Not sure about this, though since I never used RegEx Filter myself.

Comment: I am assuming that your pattern layout is printing the logger name after the log level. If that is not the logger nam it would explain why it doesn't work. Also, if HHH10001002 is not part of the message or is the start of the actual message then the regex would need to be changed. Without seeing your pattern for the pattern layout it is hard to tell you exactly what to do, but the overall technique does work.